# Where to store shared commands that are not business logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, structure, project

Accepting the fact, that business logic should be in services and remembering about
[TellDontAsk](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) one question popes up:

#### Consider following situation:

```
1) A Service, that contains business logic.
2) B SignalR hub that should notify clients.
3) C HttpController that also should notify clients.
4) D Function(Command) that can notify clients, but needs data from service(A).
```

#### Problem:

- put function (D) in service (A) => now service contains not only business logic **[BAD]**
- put function (D) in hub (B) as static => now hub should get `IHubContext`(what in fact means himself) and many more to pass as function parameters in constructor **[NOT BEAUTIFUL]**
- put function (D) in another service (E) => it would be beautiful and native, but what folder structure then project should have to separate 'business' services from 'presentation' services **[QUESTION]**

##### Update:

What problems are connected with the 3 option?

1. another service should be created and registered
2. interface for service should be created

As result: 2 Files to perform one pretty simple task, i personally think it provides to much trash in project structure, doesn't it?

###### Thank You for any idea!

Comment: personally i vote for option 3, plus some brainstorming about the naming. however i'm afraid this question is purely opinion-based. especially since all options have pros and cons.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann, thank Your for Your commitment. I have updated question to show cons that i personally see in such solution.